# how to hide the filter in ui by using angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

```
$scope.dataTableOpt = {
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100, -1], [10, 50, 100, 'All']],
        "searching": false,
        "paging": true,
        "info": false,
        "lengthChange": false
    };
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T92Ep.png

Comment: Which angular module are you using for your data-grid?

Comment: i am unable to hide the page filter option for 5 cases in a starting  page i am using data table

Comment: Please provide a description to your image and phrase your question in clear text in the body of your question, and embed the image without a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $scope.dataTableOpt = {
    //custom datatable options 
    // or load data through ajax call also
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100, -1], [10, 50, 100, 'All']],
    "searching": false,
    "paging": (listCount > 10 ? true : false),
    "info": false,
    "lengthChange": false
};
```

Comment: here listCount is nothing but total elements in the list and if the total elements are greater than 10 then paging is displayed or else not.i hope this  will work because it worked for me.Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your options object:

`"enablePaginationControls": false`

If that doesn't work, you might also want to remove the `"paging": true`

Comment: sorry bro its not working, u better see the image to know what exactly i am asking to hide